# MySQL - Group By 2 column for 1

Tags: mysql

After some days on this problem, I have decided to ask.

Before explaining what I want, here is an example of my data:

```
id     | date         | solvedate         | groupname
------ | ------------ | ----------------- | -----------------
53489  | 2016-12-01   | 2017-01-01        | Groupe 1
49848  | 2017-01-02   | 2017-01-02        | Groupe 1
46982  | 2017-01-02   | 2017-01-03        | Groupe 1
61680  | 2017-03-15   | 2017-03-15        | Groupe 2
49480  | 2017-03-16   | 2017-04-20        | Groupe 2
69870  | 2017-03-22   | 2017-03-22        | Groupe 2
```

Now I would like to count all tickets solved which were created same month.
In other words, I would like to count all tickets, group by groupe name and month.

Here is what I would like to have:

```
Groupe   | NbrOfTickets      | Month
-------- | ----------------- | -------
Groupe 1 | 2                 | January
Groupe 2 | 2                 | March
```

Here is what I'm trying (I know this is not the correct answer):

```
SELECT tickets.groupename AS Groupe, COUNT(id) AS NbrOfTickets, MONTHNAME(solvedate)
FROM tickets
WHERE solvedate BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01') AND CURDATE()
AND date BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01') AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY groupname, MONTH(solvedate)
```

So I do not want to group by date (because I will have entry I don't want to) but only by solvedate and only count tickets solved same month as they were created.

Can someone help me with that ? :).

Comment: Why do you think your query is not correct?

Comment: your query is correct.

Comment: Because I do not have result I want :(. I have a count of tickets solved but whatever the created date (date)

Comment: @EagleWatch , can you please add the result of this query.

Comment: I have:
    Groupe   | NbrOfTickets      | Month  
    -------- | ----------------- | -------  
    Groupe 1 | 3                 | January  
    Groupe 2 | 3                 | March

Comment: see your query working just fine in this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a05d6c1/4/0

Comment: I got my answer :). Thx guys.
This is the part missing in my code : 
`WHERE MONTH(solvedate) = MONTH(date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want those which were solved in the creation month you can simply add something like this (comparing year and month of creation and solvedate):

```
SELECT tickets.groupename AS `Group`,
       MONTHNAME(solvedate) AS `Month`,
       COUNT(id) AS `NoOfTickets`,
FROM tickets
WHERE year(solvedate) = year(date)
    AND month(solvedate) = month(date)
GROUP BY 1,
         2
```

Comment: Oh my god. This is exactly what I want !
I should think about that earlier ! I feel bad now :p.
Thank you so much !